# How do I use CalendarDatePicker::Date() property in UWP C++/WinRT project?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt

I want the user to pick a [Date()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.date#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_CalendarDatePicker_Date) from the CalendarDatePicker that return Windows::Foundation::IReference. However I call the [Windows::Foundation::IReference::GetDateTime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.ipropertyvalue.getdatetime) will be able to raise an exception.

Output message:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDC893A839 (KernelBase.dll) in BlankApp1.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80004001 : 'Not implemented'.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDC893A839 in BlankApp1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:winrt::hresult_not_implemented at memory location 0x00000071C2DFCB18.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDC893A839 in
>   BlankApp1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location
>   0x0000000000000000.
>
> BlankApp1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

The code that raised the exception:

```
Windows::Foundation::IReference<Windows::Foundation::DateTime> date = MyCalendar().Date();
    if (date != nullptr) {
        auto dt = date.GetDateTime();
    }
    else {
        OutputDebugStringA("You not pick a date.");
    }
```

The application breakdown in the UnhandledException of App.cpp:

```
App::App() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Suspending({ this, &App::OnSuspending });

#if defined _DEBUG && !defined DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
    UnhandledException([this](IInspectable const&, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs const& e) {
        if (IsDebuggerPresent()) {
            auto errorMessage = e.Message();
            __debugbreak();
        }
    });
#endif
}
```

The value of errorMessage is "Not implemented".

Does anyone has an idea on how to get a Date?

Comment: [mcve] perhaps?

Comment: `GetDateTime` should work, but if the implementation doesn't support that for some reason you can also use the `Value` method.

Comment: @KennyKerr Thank you for your suggestion. The **Value** method is work.